# Finding gaps between polygons using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, vba, arcgis-9.2

I am trying to build procedure for finding gaps and convert the procedure steps in to code, but i am finding some difficulty, i wonder if someone can help me with it.

the steps i planned in seek of finding the gaps between polygons(which i have tried it using the toolbox and it works) are structured as the following:

1. To find the gaps first i will merge all polygons in one polygon, but the resultant polygon still contain the gaps in it.
2. i will build new polygon from the merged polygon by using only the outer perimeter points,since there is  gaps, they will make an inner perimeter.
3. i will subtract the new polygon from the merged polygon and the remaining will be only the gaps in forms of polygons, this can be done by using [the erase tool](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=Erase%20%28Analysis%29)

hope someone can provide me with the code syntax especially for step 2 and 3 in VBA (this is the internment required for this application)

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: ArcGIS Desktop 9.2 web help is cited but is that what you are using?  If so, can you add arcgis-9.2 as a tag, please?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you tried using geoprocessing tools using IGeoprocessor interface?

Comment: Have you looked at using Topology Tools? Setting a rule that no-gaps are allowed, then referencing the topology error information.

Answer (score 3):

To do this I would create a rectangle (bounding box) polygon that surrounds your data in a new feature class and then [Union](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00080000000s000000) it with your data.  The gaps are where there are no attributes from your data - just those of the rectangle.